# How is "byte" datatype size = 1 byte while it can have 3 digit numbers?

Tags: binary, byte

> Data Type: Byte
>
> Size: 1 byte/ 8 bits
>
> Info: An integer between -128 and 127

I found this online, but I was a bit confused, I am new to binary things, sorry if I am wrong, but one single digit is 8 bits, right? So, if that datatype has 3 digits of number, how is its size = 1 byte/ 8bits??

I tried checking in [https://www.rapidtables.com](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/ascii-to-binary.html) which converts text to binary numbers, I put "127" as input and it gave me the output as

> 00110001 00110010 00110111

which is 24 bits/ 3 bytes..
which makes sense in my brain...
So what does that above information mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you confuse a string number with an integer.

A single byte (8-bits) can represent 256 numbers in the following ranges:

- signed: **-128 - 127**, max: `2 ^ 8 / 2 - 1` (`2 ^ 7 - 1`)
- unsigned: **0 - 255**, max: `2 ^ 8 - 1`

The website from your link converts a text to binary so you have 3 [ASCII](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters:

| char | dec | hex | bin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| '1' | 49 | 0x31 | 0b110001 |
| '2' | 50 | 0x32 | 0b110010 |
| '3' | 51 | 0x33 | 0b110011 |

**References:**

- [Signed number representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations)

Comment: oh i see, sorry i didn,t think like that, thank u!